# jqGrid : data from java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jqgrid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- The jQuery library is a prerequisite for all jqSuite products -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->   
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the localization file of the grid controlling messages, labels, etc. -->
    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- A link to a jQuery UI ThemeRoller theme, more than 22 built-in and many more custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <!-- The link to the CSS that the grid needs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jqGrid Loading Data - JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="jqGrid"></table>
    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

It works when I use the json file :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'data.json',
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
           { label: 'FirstName', name: 'FirstName', width: 175 },
           { label: 'LastName', name: 'LastName', width: 190 }                   
        ],

        viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data rang and total records on the toolbar
        width: 780,
        height: 200,
        rowNum: 30,
        loadonce: true, // this is just for the demo
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });
});
```

But if I use the url of my backend application as (Spring boot JPA) :

```
http://localhost:8080/customer
```

Here is an image:

[image]

I replace url with :

```
url: 'http://localhost:8080/customer',
```

no records in jqgrid ?!!

Here is an image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You run the jqgrid code as file locally and not from the server - i.e
**file:///.../index.html**. You should run this code from the web server like this by example

```
http://localhost:8000/index.html
```

and then you can use a url pointed from you.

Comment: Thank you Roshana

Comment: Can you tel me how can I do that ?